# Is there any legal "calm/silent/quiet time" in the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands

Are there any legal regulations in the Netherlands about time when it's not allowed to play music loudly or do any works which produce a lot of noise? I'm asking specifically about campings and other recreation areas. What can I do if some guests are having a very loud party during the night?

Comment: In principle you can either talk to them or call the police. Are these your guests? staying at your place (under your responsability)? or some other place?

Comment: Does the campsite have any regulations about this?

Comment: In short: No. There is no legal notion of “night quiet” in the Netherlands and, in cities, the police won't intervene if you disagree with your neighbours regarding music volume at night. I remember reading a very detailed official leaflet explaining this (don't remember whether it was published by the police itself or by the municipality of Rotterdam). Consequently, you have to change your perspective and abandon the notion that this is something you are entitled to and should force your campsite neighbours to accept. (+1 to the question)

Comment: @You'rebadandshouldfeelbad it's not a single campsite, it's an area with many small vacation homes which all belong to different hosts.

Comment: @nsn that's the problem. Talking to young party people usually won't bring any long-term result (and I suppose some other guests talk to them). And calling authorities makes only sense if there are regulations forbidding such a behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most campings will have specific rules about that, but it will vary per campsite. Enforcement too will differ per site, but generally they will try to keep all their guests happy so they will look for some compromise when there are complaints. That said, I've seen people being send away from a camping for being too noisy.

In general, if you are looking for quietness go for the smaller sites. Most people there will be looking for the same thing. And usually it's pretty clear what the 'target audience' is when looking up the website of a camping and/or reading a few reviews.

Legally, there are rules about excessive noise and causing disturbances, although those are not tied to a specific time. Besides law there may be local rules, but they very wildly and generally don't cover campsites. Either way, on a campsite go through the camp personnel first, the police will generally not show up to deal with complaints the camping should be able to deal with themselves.

Comment: Traditionally it is/was 10 PM, after which time police would act on loud noise, but local circumstances may differ.

Comment: and especially this time of year many campings make more money from the hordes of drunk teenagers partying very loudly every night for weeks on end than they do from the relatively few people wanting their peace and quiet, especially on the islands and coastal regions.